# questions about axes and mtext

Tags: r, axes

I am swimming backwards in my R knowledge.  Please help!

ExampleData:

```
Site, Aluminum_Dissolved, Federal_Guideline
M1, 0.1, 0.4
M1, 0.2, 0.4
M1, 0.5, 0.4
M2, 0.6, 0.4
M2, 0.4, 0.4
M2, 0.3, 0.4
```

I have a simple function:

```
boxplot(ExampleData$Aluminum_Dissolved ~ ExampleData$Site, col="purple", 
        par (cex.axis=2, las=2), mar=c(7,4,4,2)+0.1
```

#### X and Y axis Labels:

Once I increase the values on the axis so much, my xlab and ylab are obscured by axis text.

1. I have tried using:

   ```
   `mpg=c(3,1,0)`
   ```

   and altering values but that seems to get mess up with margin increase

   ```
   `mar=c(7,4,4,2)+0.1`
   ```
2. I tried scrapping the `xlab` and `ylab` altogether and using `mtext`, but I can't get that to give me labels outside my axis text that are parallel to the y-axis.  I have tried:

   ```
   `mtext("Dissolved Aluminum", side=2, adj=0, las)` etc....
   ```

#### 45 degree text on x-axis:

And, finally, I have tried reconstructing my x and y-axis with no avail and I can't seem to rotate my x-axis labels 45 degrees using SRT function.  I have tried:

```
boxplot(ExampleData$Aluminum_Dissolved ~ ExampleData$Site, col="purple",
        xaxt='n', yaxt='n', axis(2, cex.axis=2, xlab="Dissolved Aluminum"),
axis(1, cex.axis=2, srt=45)
```

and this doesn't work.  What am I missing.  Is there a simple way to do this I am missing...

Comment: I'm a little lost. Did you maybe intend to put all the `par` stuff in it's own line, _before_ the `boxplot` call? Because putting it in the boxplot command doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @joran.  The way I have been making my functions, I insert the boxplot call and then any modification afterwards, as per: [link]http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html  This was working ok before, but just seems to mess up when I am playing around with margins and mtext

Comment: I can't find anything at that link that remotely resembles the syntax you are using.

Comment: Specifically, both `par` and `axis` are separate functions, and they should be called on separate lines, _outside_ of any other plotting call, like `boxplot`.

Comment: @joran  I am very new at this and have just been putting my code in one line (yeah, probably ridiculous, but it was working).  Do you mean i should organize my code like this? (but I can't run this..)     _italic_**bold**'boxplot(MaiBelaData$AlD ~ MaiBelaData$Site, col="purple", ylab="Dissolved Aluminum") +
par(cex.axis=2, cex.lab=1.8)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick tutorial:

The way that plotting works in base R graphics is general thought of as a "pen on paper" model. This means that each function you call draws "on top" of what you've created up to that point. Graphical parameters can either be set *beforehand* via a call to `par`, or passed directly to the plotting function directly (with some caveats). So for example, I would have done this as:

```
par(cex.axis=2, las=2,mar=c(7,4,4,2)+0.1)
boxplot(Aluminum_Dissolved ~ Site,data = dat, 
        col="purple",ylab = "Dissolved Aluminum",xlab = "Dissolved Aluminum")
```

If you wanted custom axes, you would have done something like:

```
par(cex.axis=2, las=2,mar=c(7,4,4,2)+0.1)
boxplot(Aluminum_Dissolved ~ Site,data = dat, 
        col="purple",ylab = "Dissolved Aluminum",xlab = "Dissolved Aluminum",axes = FALSE)
axis(...)
```

Subsequent call (on separate lines) to things like `points` or `lines` would add points or lines to the graph, respectively.

The caveat with `par` is that some parameters can *only* be set by calling `par` directly, not by passing them as named arguments to plotting functions. There is a list of those (which includes `mar`) located at `?par`.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much for spending the time to explain that!  I really wasn't understanding the basic order of things.  Thank-you very much and it explains why i am getting all sorts of errors.

Answer (score -1):

@joran was right -- i think i just messed up the order of the function.  I get the axis labels working despite greater size in text using this code:

```
    boxplot(ExampleData$Aluminum_Dissolved ~ ExampleData$Site, col="purple", par(cex.axis=2, cex.lab=1.8), ylab="Dissolved Aluminum")
```

The only problem with this is that the label is very close to text, but it is alright.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, but once again, putting `par()` _inside_ of the `boxplot` call is decidedly non-standard and only works by accident. If you simply pass `cex.axis=2, las=2, mar=c(7,4,4,2)+0.1` as named arguments you'll see you get the same result.

Comment: Pleaase refer to @joran's answer.  This one is kind of bogus.